# Why is my Airflow MySqlOperator Insert Command Denied?

Tags: airflow

I'm running a dag with an insert query. Here is some of the code:

```
QUERY = '''
INSERT INTO bi.target_skus (skus)
SELECT
    distinct od.sku,
FROM
    bi.orders as od'''

t1 = MySqlOperator(
        sql=QUERY,
        mysql_conn_id = MYSQL_CONN_ID,
        task_id='target_skus',
        dag=dag)
```

It's giving me the following error:
`ERROR - (1142, "INSERT command denied to user 'xyz' for table 'target_skus'")`

A few notes:

1. Devops said my user has permission to make inserts into that table
2. Select commands work fine
3. The error message does not include the database name (bi) even though my insert query does.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a standard MySQL "not enough privileges" error.

Are you sure you can perform INSERTs with your user, regardless of what your DBA is saying? You should test the same operation using another tool (like MySQL Workbench) setting up the connection in the same way you set it up in Airflow, i.e. same user, same password, same default schema.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a privilege error from the user trying to insert but there is a comma in the insert that can cause problems too:

QUERY = '''
INSERT INTO bi.target_skus (skus)
SELECT
    distinct od.sku
FROM
    bi.orders as od'''

Comment: My bad, that comma isn't in the actual code. I added it when I simplified the query for the post.